# Read READ COMMITED transaction advantage in MySQL, high performance object model

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, transaction

I am writing high performance object model with `READ COMMITED` locking.

My question is if there is any reason to starting `READ ONLY` transaction for read only operations vs. standard SELECT not enclosed in any transaction.

**Update:**

MySQL 5.6 changes InnoDB autocommit SELECT into read-only transactions, boosting its performance a bit.

Comment: If two `SELECTs` ask for the same info, but get different answers, do you care?

Comment: Have you experimented enough to determine that you need to do anything special to achieve 'high performance'?  Do that first.

Comment: I do not see any advantage by opening READ ONLY transaction for only data reading in comparison to standard SELECT in standard autocommit mode. Actually there is a disadvantage in the overhead in start transaction and commit at the end. I am looking for maximum performance, my question is if there should be any reason to use the READ ONLY transaction. I know MySQL quite a lot, but could not answer this question. If the READ ONLY transaction is good only for prevent some changes, I do not need it, I need only best possible performance.

Comment: As I rely on the READ COMMITED locking mode, multiple SELECTs can return different answers.

Comment: "Read only transaction" is a new feature designed for performance.  It avoids a lot of locks that might otherwise slow down other transactions.  It is, of course, of no advantage if you have only one thread running.  How many active transactions to you expect at once?

Comment: I expect several hundreds concurent transactions for read and write (with locking via select for update on rows only for update via PK). Updates need RW transaction. My question is there is any advantage to starting one READ ONLY transaction with iso. level READ COMMITED vs. standard/AUTOCOMMIT SELECTs. I do not need higher isolation level, I need the best reading performance.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer to that question.  Do you have any queries that take more than a few seconds?  If so, let's see if we can optimize them in some way.